# Determining x/y direction from left-stick movement

Tags: java, libgdx

Libgdx has controller support, but I can't figure out how it works. They have a [blog post](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2724) describing it, but nothing about how to determine the x/y direction of the stick.

I want the left stick to control player movement and right stick to control player aiming.

```
@Override
public boolean axisMoved (Controller controller, int axisIndex, float value) {
    print("#" + indexOf(controller) + ", axis " + axisIndex + ": " + value);
    return false;
}
```

How do I get the x/y direction that the stick is pointing with the info given in this callback?

You can see the [full interface](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/GamepadTest.java).

Answer (score 0):

I've got no personal experience, but it'd seem logical that `axisIndex` is an index of the changed axis.

The index is really dependent on the controller you use (though, it'd make sense if 0 was X and 1 Y).

Here's a piece of the interface documentation:

```
/** An axis on the {@link Controller} moved. The axisCode is controller specific. The 
axis value is in the range [-1, 1]. The
* <code>com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.mapping</code> package hosts axes constants for known controllers.
* @param controller
* @param axisCode
* @param value the axis value, -1 to 1
* @return whether to hand the event to other listeners. */
public boolean axisMoved (Controller controller, int axisCode, float value);
```

Therefore, your best bet is to have a look in `com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.mapping` and find what you want there.

Comment: I took a look at it. It turns out there's stuff like LEFT_X/Y. Makes sense to me now, but I won't know until I try it out.